# jQuery Mobile Select Menu open on tap anywhere in Popup

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple form I'm opening inside a popup:

```
        <div data-role="popup" id="request-form" data-dismissible="false">

            <div class="ui-header">
                <h2>Request Holiday</h2>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="single-day">
                    <label><b>Date</b>: <span id="date"></span></label>
                    <select id="half-day">
                        <option value="Full">Full Day</option>
                        <option value="Morning">Morning Only</option>
                        <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon Only</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button id="request-button" data-theme="B">Request</button>            
                <button id="cancel-button" data-rel="back">Cancel</button>
            </div>            
        </div>
```

Which works fine, except when I click either of the buttons, or the label or the header in iOS, the select menu pops open - it appears to receive focus whenever a click/tap event fires in the popup.  This only seems to happen when the form is in a popup.

I originally set out to use a dialog, but that causes my original page to lose it's scrolled position when I close the dialog, and I preferred the look of the popup.

Is this a bug?  Is there a way I can stop the select automatically receiving focus?  Any other workarounds?

Comment: Do you have the Popup wrapped in other div than page div?

Comment: No, the popup div is immediately inside the page div, which is immediately inside the body.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in iphone 5 iOS 8 using safari.

Comment: Have you got any (vclick) assigned any-were on the page or other click functions that maybe interfering??. It sounds strange but i had a similar issue on a popup and traced it to that.

Comment: No, nothing like that - try this stripped down example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2497368/test.html - tap open, then tap the Request Holiday header.  As you can see from the source I'm not even doing any javascript in the stripped down version.

Comment: Try a page without anything else, only a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a hacky solution, which involves extending the popup widget, overriding a method with the same code, but commenting out the code that causes the first focusable element to receive focus when the popup is clicked:

```
$.widget( "mobile.popup", $.mobile.popup, {

_openPrerequisitesComplete: function() {
    var id = this.element.attr( "id" ),
        firstFocus = this._ui.container.find( ":focusable" ).first();

    this._ui.container.addClass( "ui-popup-active" );
    this._isOpen = true;
    this._resizeScreen();

    // Check to see if currElement is not a child of the container.  If it's not, blur
    if ( !$.contains( this._ui.container[ 0 ], this.document[ 0 ].activeElement ) ) {
        this._safelyBlur( this.document[ 0 ].activeElement );
    }
//  if ( firstFocus.length > 0 ) {
//      this._ui.focusElement = firstFocus;
//  }
    this._ignoreResizeEvents();
    if ( id ) {
        this.document.find( "[aria-haspopup='true'][aria-owns='" +  id + "']" ).attr( "aria-expanded", true );
    }
    this._trigger( "afteropen" );
},
});
```