# jquery datepicker in jquery-mobile popup, first touch is triggering select options to display in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I have a PhoneGap(v.4.2.0-0.25.0)/jQuery-Mobile(v1.4.5) app for iOS.  I am using the jquery datepicker widget (jquery-ui-1.11.3) within a jQuery-Mobile popup.  The problem I have is that when I touch anywhere on the calendar, it displays the month select options.  I have the 'changeMonth' and 'changeYear' options enabled.  I believe that this is somehow related to the jQueryMobile popup because when I simply display the datepicker on the page, outside of the popup, this issue does not happen.

The following is my popup snippet:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="sblCalendarPopup" data-history="false">
    <div id="sblCalendar"></div>
</div>
```

When I disable the 'changeMonth' and 'changeYear' options, there are no select options to display. I would appreciate any insight into why this may be happening.

Comment: After some more digging, I realized that the select menu receives focus when tapping anywhere on the popup.  Then I searched some more and found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794742/jquery-mobile-select-menu-open-on-tap-anywhere-in-popup ... I found a work-around for my specific case, by triggering a click() on the 'Today' button.  However, this forces the calendar to always display the current month/year rather than the previously selected month/year.  I am still hoping to find a fix or jQuery-mobile will fix it if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not want this odd behavior happening for any of my jQuery Mobile popups, I found a workable solution from the post: [jQuery Mobile Select Menu open on tap anywhere in Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794742/jquery-mobile-select-menu-open-on-tap-anywhere-in-popup) ... in jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js I simply commented out the following lines in _openPrerequisitesComplete():

```
if ( firstFocus.length > 0 ) { this._ui.focusElement = firstFocus; }
```

or in jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, comment out:

```
c.length>0&&(this._ui.focusElement=c),
```

This seems to work for me so far.  I can now use the fully functional jQuery UI datepicker widget.